# Get the Link in a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check if a string contains a link and print it. So far this is my code

```
string strRegex = @"(http://\w+\.\w+\.\w+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"An http://w.facebook.me  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd ahttp vhttp b... ../ .. extraordinary day dawns with each new day.";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(myMatch.Value);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
http://w.facebook.me
http://www.w3.org
```

The output should be

```
http://w.facebook.me
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd
```

In my regex i don't want to add another `\w+` because i didn't know how many slash and how long words are there will be in a link .

So how can i do this better? how can i get the link without knowing how long the link will be?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change the regex to

```
"(http://\w+\.\w+\.\w+(\/\w+)*)"
```

If you want to match links like http://w.facebook.me/ i.e. with an extra slash at the end just change it to

```
"(http://\w+\.\w+\.\w+(\/\w+)*\/?)"
```

Comment: the regex only return http://www.w3.org i need the complete link http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd